# QThread threadpool

Tags: c++, qt, threadpool

I am trying to write thread poll with QThread.

```
class ThreadPool: public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    ThreadPool(int maxThreads);
    void addTask(MyTask *task);
private:
    int maxThreads;
    QMutex mutex;
    QVector<QPair<bool, QThread>> threads;
    QThread *getFreeThread();
public slots:
   void freeThread();
};


void ThreadPool::addTask(MyTask* task)
{
    QThread *thread = getFreeThread();
    task->moveToThread(thread);
    connect(thread, SIGNAL(started()), task, SLOT(doWork()));
    connect(task, SIGNAL(workFinished()), thread, SLOT(quit()));
    connect(thread, SIGNAL(finished()), task, SLOT(deleteLater()));
    connect(thread, SIGNAL(finished()), thread, SLOT(deleteLater()));
    connect(thread, SIGNAL(finished()), this, SLOT(freeThread()));
    thread->start();
}
```

I am creating a limited number of threads in which I want to perform tasks.
However, I do not understand how to get the number of the freed thread.
I know about QThreadPool and Qtconcurrent, but I dont want to use it.
Perhaps, it is worth noting at each thread in QPair's vector is it free or not.

Comment: Just for completeness sake, there exists a QThreadPool class you can use.

Answer (score 2):

1. you do not really need a `QVector<QPair<bool, QThread>>` to keep track of all the threads in your Pool, instead use a `QList< QThread* >` which holds only the pointers to the free threads.

   ```
   private:
        QList<QThread*> freeThreads; // only free threads
        QList<QThread*> allThreads; // just to count the number of all threads
   ```
2. In the slot freeThread() use the sender() method from QObject to get the pointer of the signal sender, which in this case will be the QThread, that has become free

   ```
   void ThreadPool::freeThread()
   {
        // get the pointer to the thread that sent the signal:
        QObject* threadFreed = QObject::sender();
        if( ! freeThreads.contains( threadFreed ) )
        {
             // save the thread pointer in list
             freeThreads << threadFreed;
        }
   }
   ```
3. Finally getFreeThread() can look like this:

   ```
   QThread* getFreeThread()
   {
        if( ! freeThreads.isEmpty() )
        {
             // take the first free thread
             return freeThreads.takeFirst();
        }
        else
        {
             if(allThreads.size() < maxThreads )
             {
                // create a new thread 
                QThread* thread = new QThread(this);
                allThreads << thread;
                return thread;
             }
             else
             {
               // Maximum number of threads exceeded 
               // and no free thread is available
                return NULL;
             }
        }

   }
   ```

Also you should handle the case when a NULL pointer is returned in addTask:

```
void ThreadPool::addTask(MyTask* task)
{
    QThread *thread = getFreeThread();
    if( ! thread )
    {
        // do something else
        return;
    }
    // proceed with thread execution ...
}
```